# Pass a CloudFormation YAML list via a JSON string parameter

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to import an existing load balancer into a CloudFormation stack. The listeners must be specified as a YAML list, but there is no CloudFormation parameter type for list (array) or object, so the parameter for the YAML list must be a string. This is causing the following CloudFormation error

> Value of property Listeners must be of type List

The value of the string parameter for the listeners is set using the CLI -

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names $ELB_DNS_NAME --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[0].ListenerDescriptions[].Listener' | jq --compact-output '.' | sed -e 's/"/\\"/g'
```

Notice that the resultant JSON from the above command is escaped. I suspect that this is the root cause of the issue.

```
[
...
    {
        "ParameterKey": "ElbListeners",
        "ParameterValue": "[{\"Protocol\":\"TCP\",\"LoadBalancerPort\":443,\"InstanceProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"InstancePort\":31672},{\"Protocol\":\"TCP\",\"LoadBalancerPort\":80,\"InstanceProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"InstancePort\":30545}]"
    },
...
]
```

CloudFormation doesn't seem to offer any way of un-escaping the string parameter, so the following template fails.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  ...
  IngressLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties: 
      Listeners: !Ref ElbListeners
      LoadBalancerName: !Ref ElbName


Parameters:
  ...
  ElbListeners:
    Type: String
    Description: Listeners for the load balancer
    Default: ""
  ElbName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the load balancer
    Default: ""
```

Replacing quotes in the resultant JSON with `${quote}` in the parameters file, and then replacing `${quote}` with quotes using `!Sub` fails. It seems that the first input for `!Sub` can't be `!Ref ParameterName`.

I don't know how many listeners there will be, so it's not feasible to hardcode a list of listeners in the template and pass in multiple parameters for the ports/protocols.

How can I pass a YAML list as a JSON string parameter?

Comment: Stupid question:  I am not that experienced with YAML, but if the template is in YAML, couldn't/shouldn't  the List of Listeners be in YAML?  See here and scroll down to the YAML example:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#aws-properties-ec2-elb--examples

Comment: I looked at the documentation.  I don't believe it is actually expecting a JSON string.  It is expecting a "Type: List of Listeners" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#cfn-ec2-elb-listeners.  So, I don't think it will be successful to pass a JSON string in YAML even if you can do it.  Might I suggest a comma delimited list for each value of the listener and then use the parameter for each type.  Then use an Fn::Select.  This of course assumes you have a known number of listeners as there is no for loop logic.

Comment: @TimBassett - Yes, that's the problem. This is not a load balancer related issue, it is a CloudFormation related issue where the resource that is being imported happens to be a load balancer. The CloudFormation resource `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer` is expecting a YAML list of listeners. However, CloudFormation does not appear to provide a mechanism where it is possible to pass a YAML list via parameters. The types of parameters are very limited, leaving only `String` as a viable option. I am looking for a solution to that problem.

Comment: Do you have a known quantity of listeners, or is it variable?

Comment: Usually two (80 and 443), but it cannot be guaranteed. Hence the need to pass the whole list in, rather to parts of each listener.

Comment: I suggest you look at the CDK (https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/).  It will allow you to write code to import the json and create the ELB.  It will also allow you to have a variable number of listeners.  If you had a fixed number of listeners, you could do string delimited lists and use Fn::Select.

Answer (score -1):

You can take the content of the ElbListeners parameter and simply insert it into the template, removing it from your Parameters. The resulting template would look like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  ...
  IngressLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties: 
      Listeners:
        - Protocol: TCP
          LoadBalancerPort: 443
          InstanceProtocol: TCP
          InstancePort: 31672
        - Protocol: TCP
          LoadBalancerPort: 80
          InstanceProtocol: TCP
          InstancePort: 30545
      LoadBalancerName: !Ref ElbName


Parameters:
  ...
  ElbName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the load balancer
    Default: ""
```

Comment: The value of `Listeners` (YAML list) is not known before the CloudFormation template is deployed, and therefore must be passed via a parameter (JSON). The conundrum to which I seek an answer is how do I pass a YAML list as a JSON string?

Comment: You can't really pass in complex objects. You would need to either pass in the individual values themselves.

As an alternative to that, you could compile your object, submit it to S3, and use the [AWS::Include](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html) transform to bring it into your template.

Comment: Thanks, that is a possibility, but my reservation is that it would add further complication to the already overly complicated process of importing an existing resource into a stack. I'm quite shocked at how limited CloudFormaiton is compared to ARM templates, where this would be trivial.